# Is there an efficient way to get the count of object occurrence in another object list ? Django

Tags: django, model, list-comprehension

In my Django app, I have a few models including, but not limited to: Vehicle, Vehicle Make, and Dealership. I create a list comprehension that creates JSON objects with the vehicle make, count of occurrences for that make in the Dealerships inventory, e.g. 6 Toyotas in their inventory, and the id of that make in my Postgres DB. The problem is I have to use .count on all the vehicles in the database that are of that make, and belong to that dealership, which takes a huge toll on the database. Is there any way to speed this up, or optimize this. I've been looking through the web for potential solutions, but am coming up dry.

view function

```
try:
    dealer = Dealer.objects.get(id=1)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)

makes_map = [{
    'name': make.name,
    'count': Vehicle.objects.filter(vehicle_make=make, dealer=dealer).count(),
    'id': make.id
} for make in VehicleMake.objects.filter(
    name__in=Vehicle.objects.filter(dealer=dealer).values_list('vehicle_make__name', flat=True))
]
```

Comment: Since you're using PostgreSQL, have you considered using materialized views? Other option would be the use in-memory cache like Redis.